# Is Barrel (index.ts) deprecated from Angular 6?

Tags: angular, import, export, angular6

In Angular2, we made use of **index.ts** files extensively to make the **import** and **export** statements simpler.

Since we are upgrading to **Angular6**, getting a lot of circular dependency issues. The moment we remove or ignore these **index.ts** files, then all those dependency issues are getting resolved.

So we would like to know that, is **Barrel (index.ts)** no more used in Angular6?

If still getting used, then is there any changes, the way it was used before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not deprecated, Just don't reference them from inside of the same directory means **do not import a symbol from a barrel that export the current file, import from the file itself**.